# Preferred Product Analysis using DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, loops, text, db2, case

I have Data which looks like this:

| ID | SERVICE_TYPE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | SACCOS | 0 |
| 12345678 | RETAIL_SME | 0 |
| 12345678 | TRANS_LOGISTIC | 0 |
| 12345678 | HEALTHCARE | 0 |
| 12345678 | ENERGY | 7 |
| 12345678 | NGO | 0 |
| 12345678 | TECH_SERVICES | 0 |
| 12345678 | BUSINESS_SERVICES | 0 |
| 12345678 | RELIGIOUS | 0 |
| 12345678 | INSURANCE | 0 |
| 12345678 | EDUCATION | 0 |
| 12345678 | MICROFINANCE | 0 |
| 12345678 | LOAN_REP_COUNT | 2 |
| 12345678 | WATER_BILL | 0 |
| 12345678 | PAY_TV | 0 |
| 12345678 | MERCHPAY_OP | 1 |
| 12345678 | MERCHPAY_AM | 0 |
| 12345678 | BETTING | 0 |
| 12345678 | AMTk_BUNDLE | 0 |
| 12345678 | AMTK_AIRTIME_RECH | 1 |
| 12345678 | ELECTRICITY_BILL | 0 |
| 12345678 | W2B | 0 |
| 12345678 | P2P_UNREG | 0 |
| 12345678 | P2P_OPTK | 1 |
| 12345678 | P2P_AMTK | 1 |
| 12345678 | CASHOUT | 0 |
| 12345678 | IMT | 0 |
| 12345678 | AGRICULTURE | 0 |
| 12345678 | AVIATION | 0 |
| 12345678 | SPORTS | 0 |
| 12345678 | CONSTRUCTION | 0 |
| 12345678 | HORECA | 0 |
| 12345678 | AGGREGATOR | 0 |
| 12345678 | MEDIA | 0 |
| 12345678 | FMCG | 0 |

The goal is to find the preferred product of customer, in the way that: I get o understand customer A prefers product X(s), and the next Best offer is Product Y(s), and the Third Best Offer is Product Z (s).

For products that have same number of count they should appear in one column. for instance for this case.

It should look like this:

| ID | FIRST_PREF_LEG | SECOND_PREF_LEG | THIRD_PREF_LEG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | ENERGY | LOAN_REP_COUNT | AMTK_AIRTIME_RECH,P2P_OPTK,P2P_AMTK |

Another example is if the customer has two product with Equal CNT let say 2, that should be customer's first Pref Leg and all products should be there

If customer has only 0 CNT that we should label that customer as 'Non user' across all Pref Leg.

I have tried this:

```
WITH RankedServices AS 
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        COALESCE(SERVICE_TYPE, 'non-user') AS SERVICE_TYPE,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COALESCE(CNT, 0) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM 
        Table_name_tableA
    WHERE 
        COALESCE(CNT, 0) > 0 -- Exclude products with count 0
)
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END) AS First_Pref_Leg,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 2 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END) AS Second_Pref_Leg,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 3 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END) AS Third_Pref_Leg
FROM 
    RankedServices
GROUP BY 
    ID;
```

And here is the result:

| ID | FIRST_PREF_LEG | SECOND_PREF_LEG | THIRD_PREF_LEG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | ENERGY | LOAN_REP_COUNT | P2P_OP |

While I was expecting:

| ID | FIRST_PREF_LEG | SECOND_PREF_LEG | THIRD_PREF_LEG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | ENERGY | LOAN_REP_COUNT | AMTK_AIRTIME_RECH,P2P_OPTK,P2P_AMTK |

Comment: You can use LISTAGG( CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END,',')  instead off max(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END). And use ``dense_rank()`` for ranking.

Comment: My be typo ``P2P_OP`` -> ``P2P_OPTK``

Comment: Yes, that is typo

Comment: Is ``THIRD_PREF_LEG`` : ``MERCHPAY_OP,AMTK_AIRTIME_RECH,P2P_OPTK,P2P_AMTK`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example.
Filter `WHERE CNT>0` not used, because you will get `'non'` value for this case.

```
select Id
  ,coalesce(First_pref_leg,'non-user') AS First_pref_leg
  ,coalesce(Second_pref_leg,'non-user') AS Second_pref_leg
  ,coalesce(Third_pref_leg,'non-user') AS Third_pref_leg
from(
  SELECT Id
    ,listagg(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 and cnt>0 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END,',') AS First_Pref_Leg
    ,listagg(CASE WHEN rnk = 2 and cnt>0 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END,',') AS Second_Pref_Leg
    ,listagg(CASE WHEN rnk = 3 and cnt>0 THEN SERVICE_TYPE END,',') AS Third_Pref_Leg
  FROM 
    ( SELECT *
        ,dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CNT DESC) AS rnk
      FROM tableA
    )AS RankedServices
  GROUP BY ID
) AS Aggregated;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lzWrZd2m)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```sql
select id,
  listagg(case when dr = 1 then service_type end, ',') as first,
  listagg(case when dr = 2 then service_type end, ',') as second,
  listagg(case when dr = 3 then service_type end, ',') as third
from (
  select t.*, dense_rank() over(partition by id order by cnt desc) as dr
  from t where cnt > 0  
) x
group by id
```

Result:

```
ID        FIRST   SECOND          THIRD
--------  ------  --------------  -------------------------
12345678  ENERGY  LOAN_REP_COUNT  MERCHPAY_OP,AMTK_AIRTIME_RECH,P2P_OPTK,P2P_AMTK
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/upRnGiYY).